# Emacs 29.2 unable to find theme file

Tags: emacs, themes, dot-emacs

### I'd like to preface this post by saying that I am VERY new to Emacs.

So I have themes installed using package.el and have already verified that they are installed by running `package-activated-list)`. Checking my `.emacs.d/elpa` directory, the theme files of the different themes I've tried to install are also located within their own respective directories.

```
~/.emacs.d/elpa$ ls
adwaita-dark-theme-20231209.1033  archives  constant-theme-20180921.1012  gnupg  timu-macos-theme-20240302.1736
```

I also already have my `package.el` initialized through:

```
;; package manager
(require 'package)
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
    ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
```

However when I evaluate the following region from my `.emacs.d/init.el`, an error message is returned saying that Emacs is unable to find the theme file.

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'adwaita-dark-theme)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'adwaita-dark-theme))

(load-theme 'adwaita-dark-theme t)
```

So I've tried installing other themes to check if maybe it was something wrong with the theme source. I first tried installing the `timu-macos` theme and then `adwaita-dark-theme`. These packages were installed by changing the theme name I used in the third code snippet I provided. I've also tried installing from `package-list-packages` within Emacs but as with the others, the theme file could not be found.

I've also tried manually add the theme file to the `load-path` to no avail.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/adwaita-dark-theme-20231209.1033/adwaita-dark-theme.el")
```

**Any help provided would be much appreciated!**

Comment: The name of the theme is 'adwaita-dark', not 'adwaita-dark-theme'.
And if you're on 29.2, take a look at use-package (https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/use-package.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This theme's package name is `adwaita-dark-theme`, but the theme's name is [`adwaita-dark`](https://gitlab.com/jessieh/adwaita-dark-theme/-/blob/main/adwaita-dark-theme.el?ref_type=heads#L1222).

So, the correct way to load this theme after the wrapping package is successfully installed is to call the following:

```lisp
(load-theme 'adwaita-dark t)
```